# After baking my lights again in Unity, my character is black?

Tags: unity, lighting, lightmap, hdrp

I had to re-bake my scene several times before getting the look that I wanted. This last time, the scene looks great, but my characters are now very dark and the playable character is completely black. He lights up only when the directional light hits him.

Saying this makes me realize the problem (sort of): All the spotlights from the room's interior were probably baked while the characters were turned off, making their solution require the only real-time light in the scene in order to be seen.

Still, I didn't think the characters would be involved in the lightmap data? How do I redo the lights just for characters and moving objects? How can I fix this and keep the scene lighting?[image]

Comment: Do you have light probes set up in your scene to transfer baked light onto dynamic objects?

Comment: Oh....crap, if I had them before I don't now. Can I just throw them in the scene and they'll start working, or do I need to re-bake after?

Comment: That looks like a question you can answer yourself.

Comment: Right, touché .

Answer (score 1):

So um...kids: don't bake your lights before you set up blend-probes or all your characters and other non-static objects are only going to be lit by real-time lights. Real-time solutions might not require this but any baked-lighting solution probably will.